# Access deep-link parameters from an Android View Model's injected SavedStateHandle

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

How would I access data from a deep-link inside of an Android's Architecture Components `ViewModel` at its init-time. I have access to extras provided in the intent's `Bundle` (`intent.extras`) through a Hilt-injected `SavedStateHandle`, but when opening the Activity through a deep-link, I only have a URI (`intent.data`) on the Activity level, and nothing in the `ViewModel`.

As an example, say I'm opening my activity through something like *my-app://profile?id=123*, how would I get access to that 123 ID from an AAC ViewModel at init-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this could be to intercept the creation of the view model. The [`ComponentActivity.viewModels()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/924b7e11734c0cd506a496f448e1a96b7b86ee68:activity/activity-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/activity/ActivityViewModelLazy.kt;l=75-89;bpv=1;bpt=0) extension allows changing the `CreationExtras`, which will get passed to the `SavedStateHandle`:

```kotlin
public inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> ComponentActivity.viewModels(
    noinline extrasProducer: (() -> CreationExtras)? = null,
    noinline factoryProducer: (() -> Factory)? = null
): Lazy<VM>
```

By default, a `ComponentActivity` creates extras for its view models through [`getDefaultViewModelCreationExtras()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/0ab82fd0059cd47bb89dd1fd38b44d42a912f2c9:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity.java;l=668-679;bpv=1;bpt=0), which only grabs extras from the intent, but passing a `extrasProducer`, we can inject more things:

```kotlin
private val viewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModels(
    extrasProducer = {
        val extras = MutableCreationExtras(defaultViewModelCreationExtras)

        intent?.data?.getQueryParameter("id")?.let { queryParamId ->
            extras[DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY] = bundleOf("id" to queryParamId)
        }

        extras
    }
)
```